# select from table sql ce server between date returning 0

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows, forms, datetime

I am developing a windows form application in C#. I have a query where i want to select from date to date. the result is always 0. 
My DB is a .sdf file, and in my table I have a datetime field to store the order date as DateTime.Now, and my PC dateformat is 10.12.2014,
Can any one please help me and explain why is this hapening..! Is there any better file format to save locally.? the application will be installed on several PC's, will the datetime format be a problem .? your help is much appricaitaed.. check  please provide with some code.

```
internal static DataTable SearchItemsInOrders(string searchWord, string table, int minValue, int maxValue, out DataTable dtTable, DateTime dateFrom, DateTime dateTo)
{
    string commandText = "select A.ItemName, B.Site, B.OrderId, A.Qty, B.Requester, B.Receiver, B.Date ";
    commandText += "From tblOrderLine AS A Inner join tblOrder As B on A.OrderId=B.OrderId ";
    commandText += "where A.ItemName='" + searchWord + "' and B.Date >= '" + dateFrom.ToShortDateString() + "' and B.Date <='" + dateTo.ToShortDateString() + "' Order By A.OrderId DESC";

    SqlCeDataAdapter adp = new SqlCeDataAdapter();
    SqlCeConnection con = ConAndData.Con;

    dtTable = new DataTable();
    adp = new SqlCeDataAdapter(commandText, con);
    if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
      con.Open();
    }
    adp.Fill(minValue, maxValue, dtTable);
    return dtTable;
}
```

Comment: Please always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: First, we have to figure out the reason behind the 0 result. First try to run the query without where condition. If any rows got returned we need to change the query.

Comment: Dear Veera, When i remove the where date, i get records, but when i set the condition on date From To I get the 0 recourds.

Comment: Dear Soner, can you please modify as your sugestion.

Comment: Are you sure that the query returns anything ?

Comment: use between for date difference

Comment: @mybirhname. yes i am sure. this one returns records:string commandText = "select A.ItemName, B.Site, B.OrderId, A.Qty, B.Requester, B.Receiver, B.Date ";
            commandText += "From tblOrderLine AS A Inner join tblOrder As B on A.OrderId=B.OrderId ";
            commandText += "where A.ItemName='" + searchWord + "' Order By A.OrderId DESC";

Comment: @POHH I have tried the between, same result. can you provide with code so I can test maybe i am doing something wrong.

Comment: `select * from dbo.currenttt where [date] between '2014-10-01' and '2014-10-03'` and also check your date format

Comment: Have you tried this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this query,

```
string commandText = "select A.ItemName, B.Site, B.OrderId, A.Qty, B.Requester, B.Receiver, B.Date ";
            commandText += "From tblOrderLine AS A Inner join tblOrder As B on A.OrderId=B.OrderId ";
            commandText += "where A.ItemName='" + searchWord + "' and CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),B.Date,121) >= CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),'" + dateFrom.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "',121) and CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),B.Date,121) <= CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),'" + dateTo.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "',121) Order By A.OrderId DESC";
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

As it was suggested in comments - you have to use parameterized queries.

So, your commandText should be like:

```
string commandText = "select A.ItemName, B.Site, B.OrderId, A.Qty, B.Requester, B.Receiver, B.Date ";
commandText += "From tblOrderLine AS A Inner join tblOrder As B on A.OrderId=B.OrderId ";
commandText += "where A.ItemName=@ItemName and B.Date >= @DateFrom and B.Date <=@DateTo Order By A.OrderId DESC";
```

and later you should add parameters and values to the command:

```
adp = new SqlCeDataAdapter(commandText, con);
adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@ItemName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = searchWord; 
adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@DateFrom", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateFrom;
adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@DateTo", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateTo;
```

This also will prevent possible problems caused by incorrect date format produced by ToShortDateString().

Comment: thanks for your reply, i tried your code, I get this error No mapping exists from 'VarChar' to a known SqlDbType.

Comment: @Kamiran probably you should use NVarChar or NChar (or another type according to your db type) instead if you're using some specific versions of sql server. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for details on `SqlDbType`

Comment: I did as you suggest, but still geting 0 records.

Comment: @Kamiran Ops. I"ve found a typo in code I've suggested. Last parameter value should be `dateTo` not `dateFrom`, this means last line should be `adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@DateTo", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateTo;`. So if you just pasted that line as it was - this could be the reason of 0 records in output.